# Setting SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list() fails with "No cipher match" error

Tags: c++, openssl, gsoap

I'm trying to limit the cypher list in my gsoap ssl server using SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(). But the method returns with 0, no matter what list I provide. Without setting the list everything works fine.

I'm basically doing the same as in gsoap documentation https://www.genivia.com/doc/guide/html/group__group__ssl.html#ga3492465cdd8aa71fe746199d3842cac7

```c
    auto err = BIO_new_fp(stderr, BIO_NOCLOSE);
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers();
    CalculatorSoapBindingService service;
    service.soap->send_timeout = service.soap->recv_timeout = 5;
    if (useSSL) {
        soap_ssl_init();       // init SSL (just need to do this once in an application)
        if (soap_ssl_server_context(
                service.soap,
                SOAP_SSL_REQUIRE_SERVER_AUTHENTICATION | SOAP_TLSv1 | SOAP_SSL_NO_DEFAULT_CA_PATH,
                "server.pem", // server keyfile (cert+key)
                "password",   // password to read the private key in the keyfile
                nullptr,         // no cert to authenticate clients
                nullptr,         // no capath to trusted certificates
                nullptr,         // DH/RSA: use 2048 bit RSA (default with NULL)
                nullptr,         // no random data to seed randomness
                "testServer"     // no SSL session cache
        ))
        {
            service.soap_stream_fault(std::cerr);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        const char allowedCiphers[] = "ALL:!aNULL";
        auto rc = SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(service.soap->ctx, allowedCiphers);
        if (rc != 1) {
            ERR_print_errors(err);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
```

According to [documentation](https://man.openbsd.org/SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list.3) return code 0 means complete failure.
The error message is: 140347788101304:error:1410D0B9:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list:no cipher match:ssl_lib.c:1385:
When I run "openssl ciphers" I get the full list of ciphers.
Any ideas what I'm missing? Is the context not correctly initialized?

Comment: Call [ERR_print_errors](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/ERR_print_errors.html) to get the reason why it failed.  You may have to load the error strings first depending on your version.  See [SSL_load_error_strings](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_load_error_strings.html).  Have you loaded all algorithms first with [OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms.html)?

Comment: Updated the code according to the hint of @indiv. I get "No cipher match" error.

Comment: I don't really have any more suggestions because I don't know this soap API, but I do see that you're initializing OpenSSL yourself and then you call `soap_ssl_init`, which does it again, perhaps with different options.  The docs say you may want to call `soap_ssl_noinit` instead.  Other than that, since you said that `openssl ciphers` returns the full list, then you can look at the [source code](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/ciphers.c) and see what they do.  I suspect it's more of an initialization problem though.

Comment: It was indeed an initialization problem as @indiv suggested. I'm now calling `SSL_library_init()` instead of `soap_ssl_init()` and it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great news!  If you feel so inclined, I suggest you write an answer to this question with fixed code and mark it "answered".  Sounds like your investigation and solution could help others someday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an SSL initialisation problem. Using `SSL_library_init()` instead of `soap_ssl_init()` solved the problem.
This is my final working solution:

```
CalculatorSoapBindingService service;
service.soap->send_timeout = service.soap->recv_timeout = 5; // 5 sec socket idle timeout
if (useSSL) {
    SSL_library_init();
    BIO_new_fp(stderr, BIO_NOCLOSE);
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    if (soap_ssl_server_context(
            service.soap,
            SOAP_SSL_REQUIRE_SERVER_AUTHENTICATION | SOAP_TLSv1 | SOAP_SSL_NO_DEFAULT_CA_PATH,
            "server.pem", // server keyfile (cert+key)
            "haslerrail",   // password to read the private key in the keyfile
            nullptr,         // no cert to authenticate clients
            nullptr,         // no capath to trusted certificates
            nullptr,         // DH/RSA: use 2048 bit RSA (default with NULL)
            nullptr,         // no random data to seed randomness
            "testServer"          // no SSL session cache
    ))
    {
        service.soap_stream_fault(std::cerr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    const char allowedCiphers[] = "ECDH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!ADH:!SHA:@STRENGTH";
    auto nid = NID_X9_62_prime256v1;
    auto key = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(nid);
    if (key == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create curve" << OBJ_nid2sn(nid) << std::endl;;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);;
    }
    SSL_CTX_set_tmp_ecdh(service.soap->ctx, key);
    EC_KEY_free(key);

    auto rc = SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(service.soap->ctx, allowedCiphers);
    if (rc != 1) {
        std::cout << "no cipher list found " << rc << std::endl;
        ERR_print_errors(err);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have commented, telling what you had to change. Just showing some code (and let the reader find out the differences) is a poor answer IMHO.